# Accept payments with Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

There are lots of ready-made Flutter integrations for different payment processors for the two mobile platforms, but I can't find any that support web. Is that because there are none? 
So far I've been looking at:
 https://github.com/Techie-Qabila/stripe_api - which seems to be out of date. I'm also seeing this question asked [a bunch of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280967/payment-gateway-for-flutter-web) over the last few months. 
 Looking for any suggestions on how to accept payments in Flutter Web.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to investigate & ask this of the maintainers of the [various](https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment) [community](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk) [libraries](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment) offer Flutter plugins, whether they can target web in addition to Android/ios. In particular this one appears to support web and includes [an example](https://github.com/ezet/stripe-sdk/tree/master/example/web).

Short of that, you can try using [WebViews](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and Stripe.js as a workaround.

Comment: I've been trying to implement the one you suggested, but it doesn't support web, because it relies on uni_links. Also, WebViews does not work with web. And saying that my best bet is to ask someone to do something and hope they'll do it is hardly a solution.

Comment: Stripe doesn't provide a Flutter plugin, they offer native SDKs for iOS and Android. Web is handled by Stripe.js. If the available Flutter plugins don't or won't support what you need, then you'll need to investigate building your own: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: What about another payment processor please?
I was looking into building my own implementation now. It involves making a separate API in cloud functions that handles the communcation with Stripe, and it seems like at least one year worth of work for someone like me..Is there really no relatively simple way I can accept payments on my website?

Answer (score -1):

I've not found a good all in one solution for iOS, Android & Web that can

1. Accept digital payments on all platforms correctly (using IAP and Web solutions)
2. Accept physical payments (bypassing Apple/Android iAP)